# Unique action for individual item in .each( )

Tags: jquery, each

Is it possible to write individual code for each result within an .each() function?

What I'd like to do in [the example](http://jsfiddle.net/rJGYL/) is have each line item to have a unique color. Can this be done within the .each() ?

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('li').each(function() {
        $(this).css('color', 'purple');
    }); 
// End it all    
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rJGYL/

**Edit:** To be more concise, is it possible to add unique css to each item? Not just a color for example but say I wanted to have the first item have a font-weight of bold and the next item be italic...

Comment: Regarding your edit: The idea would be the same. Create an array of objects with CSS properties and apply them to the elements via their index.

Comment: Yes, by using CSS. If you don't want the unique css to be immediately shown, you might use jQuery just to add an activator class to some parent that activates all the unique css you declared in your css file

Comment: Check my Updated answer. You can specify other css values too. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yeah You can do this using the following code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var colors = ['black','red','purple','yellow']
    $('li').each(function(i) {
        $(this).css('color', colors[i]);
    });


// End it all    
});​
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/rJGYL/1/)

Put your colors in `colors` array.

**Update**

You can define different css for each li in a array like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var css = [{'font-weight':'bold','font-size':'25px','color':'red'}
               ,{'color':'purple'},{'color':'black'},{'color':'yellow'}]
    $('li').each(function(i) {
        $(this).css(css[i]);

    });


// End it all    
});​
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/rJGYL/5/)

You have define the `css` property's as `'key':'value'` pair in `css` array of objects.

Comment: That's more complicated than it has to be. You can pass an object to `css` directly: `$(this).css(css[i])`. No need to iterate over the properties.

Comment: thnx, I didnt know that. Updating answer. :)

Answer (score 5):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var colors = ['red','green', 'blue', 'pink']

    $('li').each(function(i) {
        $(this).css('color', colors[i]);
    });


// End it all    
});​
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/aU4kr/

You can use the index in the each function to reference an array.  If you want some more details on each it can be found here:  http://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: Or more concise: `$('li').css('color', function(i) { return colors[i]; })`.

Comment: I'd +1 Felix if that had been an answer for using the callback version of `.css()`

Answer (score 0):

You could specify an array of available colors and then use the index of each item to pick from that array:

http://jsfiddle.net/rJGYL/2/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var colors = ["purple", "red", "blue", "yellow"];

    $('li').each(function(index) {
        $(this).css('color', colors[index]);
    });


    // End it all    
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var colors= ['red','green', 'blue'];

$('li').css('color', function() {
    return colors[i];
});
```